# Des „Skriptes“ oder „Skripts“

Tags: grammatical-case, genitive

> **Diese Frage wurde auch hier (auf Englisch) beantwortet:**
>   *[Nouns with 2 genitive forms (-s/-es). When to use each?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7083/nouns-with-2-genitive-forms-s-es-when-to-use-each)*

Welches von beiden ist korrekt: „Optimierung des *Skriptes*“ oder „*Skripts*“?

Wie wird diese Form genannt (mit vorrangehendem *des*: *des Baumes, des Hundes, des Projekts* etc.)?

Comment: Genitiv?    Der Genitiv wird bei vielen Wörtern eben nur noch mit einfach-*s* gebildet statt mit *es*, korrekt ist die *es*-Form dennoch. Klingt aber manchmal etwas geschwollen. Hingegen gibt es für manche Wörte keine Kurzform (Hundes, Kindes, nicht Hunds, Kinds)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Die Form heißt *Genitiv*, sie wird manchmal auch als *Wes-Fall* oder als *2. Fall* (nach der traditionellen Zählung Nominativ – Genitiv – Dativ – Akkusativ) bezeichnet.

Typischerweise wird der Genitiv von *Skript* und vielen anderen Wörtern (*Tisch, Stift* u.v.m.) in Wörterbüchern mit einem durchgestrichenen *e* oder ähnlich dargestellt:

> Skript *n*, -<strike>e</strike>s
>   Skript *n*, -[e]s

Das bedeutet, dass *beide Formen* – *des Skripts* wie auch *des Skriptes* – gültig sind. Es hängt also von der persönlichen Vorliebe ab, welche man verwendet. Üblicher ist meistens die Form mit geschwundenem *e*, da sie kürzer ist (und das *e* ohnehin nur ein /ə/ ist). Zur besonderen Betonung, dass ein Genitiv vorliegt, wird oft die *e*-Form genommen, und das *e* als /ɛ/ ausgesprochen. Das erinnert dann oft an die Aussprache von Professor Schnauz aus der [Heinz-Rühmann-Verfilmung der *Feuerzangenbowle* von 1944](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_Feuerzangenbowle_%281944%29), besonders an:

> Wegen *däs* Schild*äs*.

(*ä* statt *e* zur Hervorhebung der überzeichneten Aussprache.)

Comment: Mit geschwundenem e. Das ist ja fast wie Kaffee mit ohne Zucker.

Comment: @CarstenS Die Argumentation lasse ich gerne gelten, wenn du mir etymologisch beweist, dass die *e*-freie Form die ältere ist.

Comment: Ist denn Kaffee ohne Zucker älter als mit? ;)

Comment: Mit ohne Zweifel.

Answer (score -3):

Genitiv: des Skript[e]s  (Duden)